# Can't pass string variable in indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexof

I am having trouble with the `indexOf()`.  I am searching for the position of a variable email address in an array of email addresses, so I can use that to look up a unique ID in another array.  I am using a for **loop** because there are also a variable number of email addresses that I will need to find, sometimes I can find the first email address but never anymore.  I am logging the variables that it should be looking up each time and they are correct.  Even more confusing is when I hard code the results of the other emails that were logged, I get the results I am looking for but never by passing the variable which is what needs to passed, which is coming up `-1`.

```
for(var i=0; i<selectedMembers.length;i=i+1){

  emailSingle=selectedMembers[i].toString();
  valuetoID=masterEmail.indexOf(emailSingle);
  IDs.push(masterIDList[valuetoID]);
  names.push(masterHandle[valuetoID]);
  console.log(emailSingle);
}
```

I have tried this many different ways with no luck

Comment: Can you show what `selectedMembers`, `masterEmail`, and `masterIdList` is?

Comment: "*I am logging the variables that it should be looking up each time and they are correct.*" - have you tested them for invisible/nonprintable characters? Please post an example of the input with which the code is not working, otherwise we can't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: var selectedMembers=input.selectedMembers.split(',');

Comment: var selectedMembers=input.selectedMembers.split(','); var masterEmail=input.masterEmail.split(','); var masterIDList=input.masterIDList.split(','); //selectedMembers is the array of email addresses we are searching for the index of in masterEmail.  We are using the indexes we found to find the ID of a users profile in masterIdList